# cs50 pset1 cash: for loop producing errors for some values

Tags: c, cs50

I want the program to give the user the least amount of coins needed for their change, but my loops are not always providing the correct answers (values 0.41, 0.75,...). I know a "while" loop would be a better solution, but can someone tell me what's wrong with those "for" loops? Thanks

```
float change;
do
{
    change = get_float("Change owed:$ ");
}
while (change < 0);

int cents = round(change * 100);

int coins = 0;

for (int quarters = cents; quarters >= 25; quarters -= 25)
{
    coins++;
}

for (int dimes = cents % 25; dimes >= 10; dimes -= 10)
{
    coins++;
}

for (int nickels = cents % 10; nickels >= 5; nickels -= 5)
{
    coins++;
}

for (int pennies = cents % 5; pennies >= 1; pennies -= 1)
{
    coins++;
}

printf("%i\n", coins);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starting point for nickles (and pennies) is wrong. For the .41 example:

the quarters loop starts at 41
the dimes loop starts at 41 % 25 = 16
the nickles loop starts at 41 % 10 = 1

That's a problem.